# Flutter background service for both android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, background-service, background-fetch

I have to try to send data from my database to endpoint every 30 minutes. I have created method for it. App will not be online all the time. How to achieve this? I stumbled across background_fetch package. Is it suitable for my need? Any advice would be appreciated.

I searched online and tried workmanager package and it worked on android,  but on iOS it only supports  one off tasks. My main concern is iOS.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _I have created method for it._ I suggest that you [edit] your question and post the code of your method and then maybe someone will be able to help you change it so that it does what you want it to do.